# Is there a way to change Magento dynamic faceted search pages into static pages?

Tags: magento, dynamic, seo, magento-1.4, faceted-search

I've just been given the task of turning around a site's plummeting SEO. One of their issues is their well ranking deep products have now been cut off due to them now being shown as part of a dynamic faceted search option. It can't and won't be indexed and the faceted search is important to the way they need to display their products.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a rewrite rule to make it appear like they are static pages, but I would recommend not doing that.

Ask yourself if Google would want to crawl search result pages: probably not. It's very common to NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW search result and tags pages because they are low quality in terms of content.

[Here's a free extension to help you accomplish just that.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yoast/extension/920/yoast-metarobots)

[Here's a helpful article on SEO in relation to Magento.](http://yoast.com/articles/magento-seo/#noindexnoncontent)

Sounds like they got hit by Panda/Penguin. You should be focusing on building links to your main categories and your homepage. Clean up poor quality pages (eg search result pages). Build deep links to products that perform well, but vary your anchor tags considerably. Without a link we can't give much more advice than that.

Comment: The internal search pages we do NOINDEX. The site may have taken a small hit but that's unrelated to this. 

The faceted search is a filter-like system, built in a similar way to the eBay and Amazon product filters. Not actual searches.

So we will have "Product Category" page and that will show all of the products within that top level category. The faceted search allows you to then select "Product Type A", "Product Type B", "Colour A", "Colour B" etc. At the moment these are generating dynamic string URLs, but the site used to have a static page which we would've bene able to optimise to.